# How to get all p tags between and after h2 tags in Jsoup

Tags: java, html, jsoup, html-parsing

I have HTML like this

```html
<h2 id="17273">bla bla bla 1</h2>
<p>Text i need</p>
<p>Text i need</p>
<p>Text i need</p>
<h2 id="45626">bla bla bla 2</h2>
<p>Text i need</p>
<p>Text i need</p>
<p>Text i need</p>
<h2 id="78519">bla bla bla 3</h2>
<p>Text i need</p>
<p>Text i need</p>
<h2 id="72725">bla bla bla 2</h2>
<p>Text i need</p>
<p>Text i need</p>
```

I want to extract all p tags after/between h2 tags and map it with the above h2 tags like this:

```
[(h2 with id 17273 = all p tags below it), (h2 with id 45626 = all p tags below it)]
```

To be honest, I don't know how to achieve that, I've tried few things like `doc.siblingElements()` and some other things, but I was not able to achieve something like that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the ***< h2 >*** and ***< p >*** tags are not linked in any way, you can use regex to artificially create dependencies between them:

```
        String x = html //your html String
            .replaceAll("</p>\\s+<h2", "</p></parent>\n<h2")
            .replaceAll("<h2", "<parent><h2")
            + "</parent>";
```

Then using Jsoup is relatively simple:

```
    Document doc = Jsoup.parse(x);
    Elements parents = doc.getElementsByTag("parent");
    for (Element e : parents) {
        Elements h2 = e.getElementsByAttribute("id");
        String id = h2.attr("id");

        Elements pElements = e.getElementsByTag("p");
        List<String> pList = new ArrayList<>();
        for (Element p : pElements)
            pList.add(p.text());

        System.out.println("h2 with id " + id + " = " + pList);
    }
```

The output received:

`h2 with id 17273 = [1 Text i need, 1 Text i need, 1 Text i need]`

`h2 with id 45626 = [2 Text i need, 2 Text i need, 2 Text i need]`

`h2 with id 78519 = [3 Text i need, 3 Text i need]`

`h2 with id 72725 = [4 Text i need, 4 Text i need]`